# I wanted to know if there is any way to turn the bot command into an on_message event command?

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is the code I am working with:

```py
import discord
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord.utils import get

def IsTeam(role):
  Value = False
  AllTeams = [] # Add all teams in here.
  if role in AllTeams:
    Value = True
  
  return Value

@bot.command()
async def sign(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, arg=None):
  if not member:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a username.")
  elif arg == None:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a team.")
  else:
    try:
      Role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=arg)
      if Role == None:
        await ctx.send("This is an invalid role.")
      else:
        pass
    except:
      await ctx.send("Unexpected Error Occured.")
      return

    if Role >= ctx.author.top_role:
      await ctx.send("You cannot add a role that is higher then your current role.")
    else:
      if IsTeam(Role):
        if Role in ctx.author.roles:
          await member.add_roles(Role)
          await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been signed to `{role}`')
```

I wanted to know if I can make the

```py
@bot.command()
async def sign(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, arg=None):
```

command into an event on_message such as like:

```py
@bot.event()
async def on_message(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, arg=None):
```

while doing the same things the command does.
sorry if I am not explaining this clearly.

Comment: Why do you want to do like that?

Comment: because I wanted it to look cleaner because this is a sign bot so I want it to do something like this: https://gyazo.com/df53c2e762b9b7000b91c2b035a360f2

Comment: I still don't understand. You can't convert a command to a `on_message` event but you can nearly do the same things with both of them. So can you make it a little bit clear what you wanted?

Comment: So basically what I am trying to accomplish, is for instance when someone says message :TeamEmoji: sign @User#0000 I want it to give that person the team role. Sorry if my explaining sucks :(

Comment: so the person that was pinged gets the role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you're trying to give a role to a user when someone mentions him/her with a specific prefix. In this case, your prefix is a `emoji+ sign`. You can use the `on_message` event for this. But in the `on_message` event, you can only use the `message` parameter. And also, you need to get the emoji id by typing `\:TeamEmoji:` in your discord chat. It will return something like `<:TeamEmoji:123456789>`. So you can basically do:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('<:TeamEmoji:1234567890> sign'):
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='role name')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send('Successfully signed to <:TEAM:123456789>')
```

Comment: great the role part works, now what if I wanted the bot to send something like `Successfully signed to <:TEAM:123456789>`

Comment: tysm for your help

Comment: uh so I figured out that I also wanted to add 2 reactions with this 
```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:JAX1:764860878512062505> offer'):
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>.')
    if message.content.startswith(f"{member.mention} Has been offered by <:JAX1:764860878512062505>"):
      emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='<:Accept:764926510673952859>')
      await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
```

Comment: Can you make another question, because it's unrelated with this one and it's hard to read while it's in the comments.